# Fire multiple async tasks and only update result from latest task

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

I've been tinkering with Blazor and came upon an async/await problem. I've added a search input field that triggers an asynchronous operation which returns a search reulst to the user when the user starts typing. The problem is that the asynchronous tasks completes in the wrong order. The first task fired returns and invalidates the result of a later task that have already completed.

I've come up with an solution that involves keeping track of the tasks but is this the right thing to do or am I going about this the wrong way?

My current solution looks like this:

```
        private List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();

        protected async Task OnSearchTermChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchTerm = e.Value.ToString();

            if(SearchTerm.Length >= 3)
            {
                SearchResult = null;
                var task = AdService.SearchUsers(SearchTerm);
                runningTasks.Add(task);
                var result = await task;

                if(task == runningTasks.Last())
                {
                    SearchResult = result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SearchResult ??= new List<AdUser>();
                SearchResult.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that a task is "last"? Won't more tasks get added as the user types?

Comment: I believe that your approach is correct - you really need to track tasks and check if the just completed task is the latest one or not. I can only suggest to store only the last ran task instead of the whole list. And you can also think about cancelling the previous tasks before starting the new one.

Comment: What do you want to really achieve? Always the last fired query result is the important - so the earlier ones can be dropped, or you need results of all the fired requests?

Comment: I believe [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0) could help you out. Task.WhenAll returns a task when all other tasks are completed, so you can await that

Comment: Is the `AdService.SearchUsers` method cancelable? Does it take a `CancellationToken` parameter?

Comment: no it is not cancelable. and yes it is always the latest task fired that is the important so I guess i should skip the list.

Comment: You could have a timer as well, so there is a little delay (0.5 to 1 secs maybe) after a change (key stroke) before doing anything with it, then if the user types 10 letters in quick succession the event only fires for the last letter and not 10 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use what I call an "asynchronous context" for this kind of scenario (probably a really bad name, given "context" can mean so many things these days). You just need some kind of unique value (`new object()` is sufficient), capture this value into a local variable before the `await`, and then compare it after the `await`. If they don't match, then that code knows it's no longer the current one.

```
private object _context;

protected async Task OnSearchTermChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
  SearchTerm = e.Value.ToString();

  if (SearchTerm.Length >= 3)
  {
    var localContext = _context = new object();
    SearchResult = null;
    var task = AdService.SearchUsers(SearchTerm);
    var result = await task;

    if (localContext == _context)
    {
      SearchResult = result;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    _context = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `context` you could also call it `ticket`. Or `ticketToRide` for more style points. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are, generally spoken, sequential and parallel compositions (for async operations). If you want things to happen in some certain order (which you want indeed), you can't run things in parallel. See the code below:

```
var enumerableOfTasks = ... // whatever enumerable of tasks in some desired order
foreach (var task in enumerableOfTasks) await task;
```

...all the magic happens at the `await task` point. It won't let next task to be executed unless current task is completed. That **guarantees** you that the last executed task wont be overwritten by some predecessor due to race condition.

Comment: Looks like the author really don't care about sequential execution, but only care to get the last result and drop out all others. So, the parallel execution is good for the author. If I'm right, then switching to the fully sequential task execution does not looks as a good solution here.

Comment: @Serg I am not certain. If the author will confirm that, I would change my answer.

Comment: no I don't care about sequential execution cause I don't know when the user will type something.

Comment: @csharpskolan that’s not a problem if you can cancel ongoing computation when new key is hit; that’s a classical way to achieve the desired order of execution. Can you pass the cancellation token to cancel any inflight computation first and then run the current one, which is the latest?

Comment: no I'm not sure I can cancel the underlying PrincipalSearcher or if the wait for cancelation has too much impact on user experience. Maybe I will give it a go.

Comment: Then you have to fallback to locking. Time stamp could be used as ordering criteria. Do you want me to update my answer with simple illustration?